# Angular 5 and Sass : in Bootstrap 's _reboot.scss file '@at-root' error : at-rule unknown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, angular5, lint

I want to include Bootstrap's scss files in my project.

But when I open _reboot.scss file VS Code complains about :

```
    // IE10+ doesn't honor `<meta name="viewport">` in some cases.
    @at-root {
      @-ms-viewport {
        width: device-width;
      }
    }
```

> 'file:///[...]/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss'
>
> severity: 'Error'
>
> message: 'at-rule unknown' at: '37,1'
>
> source: 'scss'
>
> code: 'css-unknownatrule'

I created the project with ng new  and opened it with VS Code. I don't know much about Lint (configuration, etc).

How can I get rid of this error ?